# Running a task in background?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, timer, scheduled-tasks

```
int CreateSocket()
{
        socklen_t len = sizeof(client);
       // Socket creation for UDP
       acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
       if(acceptSocket==-1)
       {
         printf("Failure: socket creation is failed, failure code\n");
         return 1;
       }
       else
       {
         printf("Socket started!\n");
       }

       //non blocking mode
      /* rc = ioctl(acceptSocket, FIONBIO, (char *)&flag);
          if (rc < 0)
          {
                     printf("\n ioctl() failed \n");
             return 0;
          }*/

          //Bind the socket
     memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
     addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
     addr.sin_port=htons(port);
     addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
     rc=bind(acceptSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
     if(rc== -1)
     {
       printf("Failure: listen, failure code:\n")    
       return 1;
     }
     else
     {
       printf("Socket an port %d \n",port);
     }    
     if(acceptSocket == -1)
     {
         printf("Fehler: accept, fehler code:\n");
          return 1;
     }
     else
     {
     while(rc!=-1)
         {
        rc=recvfrom(acceptSocket,buf, 256, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &len);
         if(rc==0)
         {
           printf("Server has no connection..\n");
           break;
         }
         if(rc==-1)
         {
             printf("something went wrong with data %s", strerror(errno));
           break;
         }
       //  XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );
          }


     }

       close(acceptSocket);   
       return 0;

     }    

void checkTasks()
{
    int i;
for( i =1; i<= 100 ;i++)
{
    if(++task1_counter ==2 )
    {
        task1_counter = 0;
        makeTimer("First Timer", &firstTimerID, 2, 2);   // creating the timer for 2ms
    }
    else if(++task2_counter == 10)
    {
        task2_counter = 0;
        makeTimer("Second Timer", &secondTimerID, 10, 10);    //creating the timer for 10ms


    }
    else if(++task3_counter == 100)
    {
        task3_counter = 0;
        makeTimer("Third Timer", &thirdTimerID, 100, 100);  //creating the timer for 100ms
    }
    else
        printf("error\n");

}

}


 }


int main()
{


     CreateSocket();            //initializing all the foreground tasks


     while(1)
     {

                 checkTasks();
     }
}
```

CreateSocket : This api is recieving data from the client continuously. I called recvfrom api inside the while loop within the CreateSocket function (which is not shown in the above code). I am calling the checkTasks within the while loop in main function. It is checking for the counter and calling the makeTimer ()  function call : This function definition is for creating a timer and call the task for every 2ms , 10ms and 100ms by signal.

my Question : once calling a init function in the main() : will it be recieving the data from the client and will in the background the checkTasks will be keep on running ?? Is it right ??

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: We need more information. CreateSocket and makeTimer does exactly what? Are they from some library that you can point out?

Comment: CreateSocket : it will be recieving the data from the client. The while loop inside the main function - will be running in the back ground ??

Comment: Is the CreateSocket already running in the background ie, is the code flow coming till the while loop. If yes, then the CreateSocket that listens and the while loop will run in parallel.

Comment: CreateSocket is recieving the data from the client via the ip address and port number (I am calling inside the init function call of main). The checkTasks should be in running in paralle. So I added in the while loop of main. is it right ??

Comment: Yes, I would assume so. However, if you could provide us the CreateSocket code as well, then it will be helpful in understanding exactly.